# CakePHP hasMany checkbox

Tags: cakephp, checkbox, has-many

I have two tables: Ingredients and Customers. The relationship between them is that Customers hasMany Ingredients. By default when doing the cakebake using the console, the only way to change them is by assigning an ingredient to the customer in the Ingredients page. However, I want to have in Customers page a checkbox list of Ingredients that can be assigned. Is it possible to do this? If yes, how?

**edit:**

What I have done until now is that I add this code to my add.ctp:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Ingredient',
        array('label'=>'',
        'type'=>'select',
        'multiple'=>'checkbox',
        'options'=>$ingredients));
```

However, it gives me "Undefined variable: ingredients" error when I tried to open the add view.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried to write some code instead of relying on the bake process?

Comment: I do it by using the usual PHP. But I still don't know how to make it work.

Comment: "What have you tried?"

Comment: Great!  Now - what did that display, and how does that differ from what you expected?  (I suggest using this feedback and editing your question (or deleting it and starting a new one if you don't yet have privileges to edit)

Comment: I don't think you're listening.

Comment: Do you mean your instruction, Dave? I have deleted as you instructed. What's next? I admit that I'm still kinda blurry about cakePHP.

Comment: Cake bake will only take you so far. You will need to edit your `view.ctp` to display the list of ingredients for this customer, and edit `edit.ctp` to display the list of ingredients with checkboxes so you can edit the ingredients.

Comment: I meant to delete this question, and start fresh on a new question that includes some actual data of what you've tried, what happened, what you expected to happen...etc etc.

Comment: The thing is that I do not know how to accomplish my objective. As I am still a novice user of cakePHP. By novice, I mean really-really-really beginner. I wish you can help me, Annabel.

Answer (score 0):

You want and need a HABTM relationship. Different customers can access and use the same ingredients. Look at the [docs here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) yours would be very similar to different Posts using same Tags.

Comment: However, it is stated that the relationship needs to be hasMany. It is for my assignment. I'm hitting a dead-end here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error:

> "Undefined variable: ingredients"

It sounds like you haven't declared this variable in your controller, and set it so that the view can use it. Without knowing your code, you would probably need do do something like this (please note I am guessing what your application structure looks like and have not tested this code).

**CustomersController.php**

```
// The controller action for your view
public function view() {

    // Get the ID and name of all your ingredients
    $ingredients = $this->Ingredient->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array('id', 'name'),
        'order' => 'name',
        'recursive' => -1
    ));

    // We will use this array to store all the HTML select options
    $ingredientOptions = array();

    // Loop through all the ingredients and add them to the select
    // options in a format that is suitable for CakePHP to use in
    // the view to build your HTML select menu.
    foreach ($ingredients as $i) {
        $ingredient = $i['Ingredient'];
        $ingredientOptions[$ingredient['id']] = $ingredient['name'];
    }

    // Make the variable available to the view
    $this->set('ingredients', $ingredientOptions);
}
```